# How to get rid of more than one million ghostfiles?

Tags: lubuntu, filesystem, bleachbit

I periodically run Bleachbit 1.0 on my Lubuntu machine (kernel 3.13.0-35-generic). Last time, I checked the option to wipe free disk space, mainly to try it. The program got stuck on a message saying it would be done in about one minute. I killed it after several hours, but I am afraid my Linux system is messed up. First, I found a new folder containing several hundred thousand files in my home directory (can't remember its name: it looked like a random alphanumeric sequence). I was able to remove it using "rm -rf ", it took almost one hour.
The problem is that, when I checked my inodes with "df -i", I got a huge amount for IUsed:

```
    Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
    /dev/sda6        2899968 1725783   1174185   60% /
    none              220155       2    220153    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev              215362     514    214848    1% /dev
    tmpfs             220155     521    219634    1% /run
    none              220155       3    220152    1% /run/lock
    none              220155       1    220154    1% /run/shm
    none              220155      16    220139    1% /run/user
```

Almost two million inodes? The whole of my filesystem uses some 10 GBytes. I browsed the web and tried to see whether a large amount of little files had been created somewhere.

```
    ae:/ $≻sudo find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
    [sudo] password for ae: 
    15 tmp
    88 opt
    129 sbin
    132 bin
    287 boot
    1180 etc
    3449 home
    5519 lib
    8101 var
    96802 usr
    1558827 root
```

This is weird. In addition to the listed directories I just have two links in my root dir: to initrd.img and to vmlinuz. Nothing in lost+found:

```
    sudo ls -l lost+found/ 
    [sudo] password for ae: 
    total 0
```

On the other hand, both ls and "find . -iname \*" don't see any of the million and a half files reported above.

I am very much afraid that my filesystem is in trouble. I created a file forcefsck in my root dir and rebooted, but fsck says the disk is ok. So... have I to shred the partition and recover it from a Clonezilla backup? I'd prefer to find out what the problem exactly is and fix it. I'd be grateful if you can help.
I have a suggestion too. I can't be sure that my problem is caused by Bleachbit but I read (too late) that several people complained about Bleachbit getting stuck while attempting to wipe free space. Bleachbit might warn users that the wiping feature is experimental and possibly harmful.

Comment: [BleachBit 1.0](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/news/bleachbit-10) notes this as a known issue, and you can see it by clicking the Help menu and clicking Release Notes.  [BleachBit 1.2](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/news/bleachbit-12) stopped making these files, and it is too bad Ubuntu does not update BleachBit except with a new release of Ubuntu. Everyone else who has had this problem resolved it by deleting the folder you described that took one hour.  I wonder in your case if the used inodes cause any practical problems?

Comment: No practical problems -- yet. But having some one and half million used inodes unaccounted for, and as many invisible files in my root directory makes me a bit anxious. You know, like feeling that a time bomb _might_ be hidden somewhere in my house. :-) Good to know that Bleachbit 1.2 stopped making such files, I just can't understand why Ubuntu does not include Bleachbit in its Software Update. Almost everything else is updated, and I installed Bleachbit in the standard way (apt-get install etc.).

Comment: In general, the philosophy behind packaging is not to give a feature-changing release to users without them explicitly seeking it. The regular updates you receive are only for security holes and critical bug fixes. Feature-changing upgrades are only provided to users who explicitly enable Backports - Learn more: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports . Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic includes Bleachbit 1.2 in its repos. You could request that this new package get backported to Trusty: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports#Requesting_a_Backport Note: It's easier than it looks :-)

Comment: @drkokandy How would you define a critical bug? My slash root folder now contains a folder called "6jF8vak8 H", size is some half GB, files one million and a half. If I try to list its contents my pc practically freezes and 95% of my 2GB RAM gets used up -- btw, it's not released if I kill the process. I'd say this is the worst attack against my filesystem I ever had to face ;-) Worst thing is, I don't know what else may have gone astray. As to enabling Backports, I decided long ago not to do it, for several reasons. I'll try to get rid of the weird dir in slash root and see what happens.

Comment: General bug importance explained here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Bug%20importances - "high" or "critical" bugs would possibly be fixed. Nothing can happen without first reporting the bug - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs . I don't know if this would rise to the level of "Critical bug fix", which is why I recommended requesting a backport of the 1.2 Utopic package. Or, if you upgrade to utopic or reinstall using 14.10 release (you mentioned considering wiping the partition in the OP), the bleachbit package available there will not repeat this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all those mini files, I might suggest running these two commands:

```
cd /    
rm -r 6jF8vak8\ H
```

(if "/6jF8vak8 H" is the directory hosting all those files like you mention in the comment.)

If this command fails, it might be because you lack permission to write to that directory, in which case you would need to use sudo - which is potentially dangerous in the root directory.

**Use extreme caution and double-check your spacing.** In fact, I would recommend typing in the terminal "rm -r 6jF" (or whatever the first few characters are) and hitting tab, which should auto-complete the directory. If it doesn't auto-complete (and you are in the root directory), don't run the command. Using this method will ensure that you don't accidentally run rm -r on the root directory itself.

Other warnings:

- I have no idea what effect removing those files will have on bleachbit.
- Running this command on a million files will probably take a significant amount of time.

Comment: As I mentioned I would do, I actually got rid of it. Removal of the folder was not a problem: sudo rm /root/6jwhatever (it was in my slash root). No unwanted effects -- up to now ;-) -- and inodes add up fine. I think I'll go on with my present version of Ubuntu, using Bleachbit just for routine cleanup. In these two days I have learned a lot about the difficulties of wiping out free disk space -- I'm only happy I don't really need it! But it seems to me that a command such as "cat /dev/zero > tmpfile" then "rm tempfile" would more or less do the same as Bleachbit in this connection. Thanks!